# Matplotlib: user defined plot function print twice

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to create a plot with a function, it will return a fig so later on I can redisplay it when needed.

The function goes like this:

```
def simple_plot(ax = None):
    if ax is None:
        fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    a = [1,2,3,4]
    b = [3,4,5,6]
    plt.plot(a, b,'-', color='black')
    return fig
```

If I run `simple_plot()`, it would print the plot twice, like this:

[image]

Notice: if I run `fig = simple_plot()`, it will only print once, and I can use `fig` to reproduce the plot later in `Ipython Notebook`

1. How can I make it only print once if I run `simple_plot()`?
2. I'm not sure if I defined the function correctly, what would be a good way to define a function to make plot?

Comment: Your problem isn't very clear, could you have a read through and try to fix some of the issues?

Comment: @Jezzamon, I have update my question, please see it again, thanks.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This is a side effect of the automatic display functionality of the Jupyter Notebooks. Whenever you call `plt.plot()` it triggers the display of the plot. But also, Jupyter displays the return value of the last line of every cell, so if the figure object is referenced as the last statement of the cell, another display is triggered. If the last statement of the cell is an assignment (`fig = simple_plot()`), the return value is `None` and thus a second display is not triggered and you don't get the second plot.

Comment: This seems very inconvenient for people writing packages that produce custom plots.  Is there no way to write a function that returns a plot but doesn't require unusual user behavior to avoid having the plot duplicated?

Comment: Excellent answer. Just wanted to add that it works fine without adding the semi colon as well. Simply just doing an assignation to object 'fig' in your last line of the cell as @foglerit has stated.

Answer (score 13):

Just add `plt.close()` before `return`, like this:

```
def simple_plot(ax = None):
    if ax is None:
        fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    a = [1,2,3,4]
    b = [3,4,5,6]
    plt.plot(a, b,'-', color='black')
    plt.close()
    return fig
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove your return statement

Ipython Notebook is plotting once when you execute `plt.plot(a, b,'-', color='black')` and a second time when you return your `fig` object to the console.

You could as well keep the return statement, but store the returned value into a variable and plot the figure again just by executing `fig`.

[image]

Comment: This means I can't run `simple_plot()`? The variable assignment `fig = simple_plot()` is quite unnecessary when I don't need the `fig`.

Comment: You can but then you don't want a return statement because that will cause the double plot (or you could add the semicolon like jonnat's answer suggested)

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered this thing. Indeed this is a side effect of the automatic rendering engine embedded in the Jupyter Notebook.

I've found this simple hack. Just use `;` after the plot()

for e.g. :

```
plt.rc("figure",figsize=(8,8))
seasonal_decompose(df,model='additive',period=4).plot();
```